# read this xml with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm having trouble reading this xml with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/VLtqY/2/

XML:

```
<myElements type="AA" coID="A923">
 <element1>01</element1> 
 <element2>02</element2>
 <element3>03</element3>
</myElements>
```

I'm looking for the following output:

```
element1=01
element2=02
element3=03
```

A little help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to wrap your `xml` variable in a call to the jQuery function, as in  `$(xml)`. Then, a call to `children()` will get all of your target elements.

Here's a very basic (and sloppy), working example of iterating through the elements, but it's just the selector that needs changing:

```
var xml = '<myElements type="AA" coID="A923"><element1>01</element1> <element2>02</element2><element3>03</element3></typeData>';

var myOutput = $("#output");

myOutput.append("=== start ===<br />");
$(xml).children().each(function () {
    var xmlnode = $(this);
    myOutput.append(this.tagName + xmlnode.text() + '<br/>');
});

myOutput.append("=== end ===");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UByfW/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('*', xml).each(function () {
```

replacing the the line

```
$(xml).find("myElements").each(function () {
```

or

```
$(xml).children().each(function () {
```

The reason is self-explanatory: you must fetch the children, not the root element.

Comment: (+1) Thanks, i wish i could give you both credit. But he had the "this.tagName" which also showed me how to retrieve the tagname value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `parseXML` (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)) function to parse the string of XML into an XML document object. Just add this line somewhere between the variable declaration and your `each` loop:

```
xml = $.parseXML(xml);
```

The rest of it should work fine then. You can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLtqY/5/).

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest ajax for this. IE hates the way jquery grabs the xml.I have been using this for a very long time with lots of success and no problems.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path-to-file.xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: function(data){
                            var xml;    
                            if (typeof data == "string") {
                               xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                               xml.async = false;
                               xml.loadXML(data);
                            } else {
                               xml = data;
                            }
                        alert($(xml).find('element1').text());
                                            alert($(xml).find('element2').text());
                                            alert($(xml).find('element3').text());
                    },//END SUCCSESS
    error: function(){
        alert("Sorry, There was an error loading this information. Refresh the page or try again later. ");
        history.go(-1);
    }
});//END AJAX CALL
```

I know this looks like a lot, but it really isn't that bad. Put your path to your xml, in the .each() do what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry about formating, damn tabs and spaces get out of control sometimes